# Middleware after login

Tags: laravel

I want Middleware to run right after login for two-step verification.

I have tried to add the following line
'login' => \ App \ Http \ Middleware \ TwoFactorVerify :: class,
inside protected $ routeMiddleware in the Kernel.php file.

Answer (score 0):

You want your middleware to run after the `Authenticate` middleware which checks every request for authentication. Register your middleware in Kernel.php, then on your desired route do like so:

`Route::get('example', 'ExampleController@example')->middleware(['auth', 'login']);`

And if you want your middleware to apply on a group of routes, do like so:

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'login'])
    ->group(function () {
        Route::get('example', 'ExampleController@example');
        Route::get('example2', 'ExampleController@example2');
    });
```

You can set `two_factor_verified => true` after a user has verified the code. Then, in `TwoFactorVerify` middleware, you can check like so:

```
if($request-session()->get('two_factor_verified'))
{
    return $next($request);
}

return new TwoFactorNotVerifiedException();
```